# Any very user friendly resources on the Baum-Welch algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, hidden-markov-models

I'd like to understand the [Baum-Welch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baum%E2%80%93Welch_algorithm). I liked [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zDARfKVm7s&feature=related) on the Forward-Backward algorithm so I'd like a similar one for Baum-Welch.

I'm having trouble coming up with good resources for Baum-Welch. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome! Maybe it would be better to read the Wikipedia article and the references linked there and then post focused questions about details you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though he doesn't say the name Baum Welch specifically, nor HMM's (until the very end) Jason Eisner does a great job covering Expectation Maximization here:

videolectures.net/hltss2010_eisner_plm/

Comment: Can you please take some time to improve this answer by adding a brief summary of the explanation in the video, possibly highlighting why it's good? Also, if you can provide a little more information for reference (in case the link changes), that would be helpful. Please flag this comment as obsolete when you have implemented these changes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A [simple web search](https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=baum-welch+algorithm+video) leads to a whole [lecture](http://vimeo.com/7343520) by [Christopher Lee](http://thinking.bioinformatics.ucla.edu/). I did not watch it entirely, but it seems to be a slow, thorough take on the algorithm with an example walk-through on paper similar to the video you link (if longer).

Comment: sweet, i'll check it out, and wait to see if any more responses come in.